# Add Class to div that Contains innerHTML String

Tags: javascript, css, xpath, innerhtml

I am trying to add a CSS class to each `div` on a page that contains the string `Subject:`

I tried

```
var elList = document.querySelectorAll("div");
elList.forEach(function(el) {
  if (el.innerHTML.indexOf("Subject") !== -1) {
    console.log(el);
    el.setAttribute('class', "newClass");
  }
});
```

but it didn't return any nodes. And also

```
var headings = document.evaluate("//*[contains(normalize-space(text()), 'Subject:')]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
while(thisHeading = headings.iterateNext()){
  thisHeading.setAttribute('class', "newClass");
  console.log(thisHeading);
}
```

which returned an `XPathResult` that didn't seem to have any nodes as part of the object.

This is what the HTML looks like, although it is deeply nested inside the document body.

```
<div class="note-stream-header">Subject: Please Reply to This</div>
```

**How can I select all nodes that contain a string and add a class to them with JS?**

Comment: Your original code looks looks like it's on the right path.  Can you post a complete code snippet with sample HTML document?

Comment: I just uploaded an `HTML` block.

Comment: Just tried your code, works fine.  http://jsfiddle.net/c12ya4nq/1/

Comment: Hm. I wonder if it's executing before the nodes finish loading on the page. I'm trying to use it as part of a Chrome extension.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine, but since you are interested in the content of an element, use `.textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.

See additional comments inline.

```js
// .forEach is not supported in all browsers on node lists
// Convert them to arrays first to be safe:
var elList = Array.prototype.slice.call(
    document.querySelectorAll("div"));
    
elList.forEach(function(el) {
  // Use .textContent when you aren't interested in HTML
  if (el.textContent.indexOf("Subject") > -1) {
    console.log(el);
    el.classList.add("newClass");  // Use the .classList API (easier)
  }
});
```

```css
.newClass { background-color:#ff0; }
```

```html
<div>The subject of this discussion is JavaScript</div>
<div>The topic of this discussion is JavaScript</div>
<div>The queen's royal subjects weren't amused.</div>
<div>Subject: textContent DOM property</div>
```

Comment: Also a good idea to use *classList* instead of *setAttribute*. :-) But I think *Array.from* would be better than using *slice*. What is the incidence of *NodeList* not having *forEach*? If it's an issue, why not `Array.prototype.forEach.call(NodeList, ...)`.

Comment: @RobG `Array.from` is ECMA 6 and not supported by browsers that don't support `.forEach` on node lists (which includes any version of IE). You could use `.call()`, but then you have to deal with `this` binding, while `.slice` returns an Array that you can cache and continue to use beyond that one statement.

Comment: I don't think *this* is an issue, it's undefined unless it's passed to the callback. But if there is a need to reuse NodeList as an array, *slice* makes sense.